# SocketAppender via UDP: possible?

Tags: java, logback

I have a remote server listening on an UDP port.
I'd like to log to that port, but from the documentation the logback's SocketAppender goes on TCP.

Isn't there a way to make it go on UDP? Or is there another appender?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't there a way to make it go on UDP?

There is no way to make `SocketAppender` go to UDP.  It uses a `Socket` not a `DatagramSocket`.

> Or is there another appender?

There is no UDP appender in the logback codebase.   However, there are some 3rd-party UDP appenders on github, etcetera: Google for `logback` + `appender` + `udp`!

---

My first reaction to this was "why would you send logging traffic over an unreliable transport?".  However, it seems that people do this.  Logging to `logstash` via UDP seems to be "the thing".